# is websocket good for building geolocalized mobile applications?

Tags: mobile, geolocation, websocket

Say that I have to build a geolocalized app. What will happen is that:

- thousands users will be using it at the same time
- while the user will move around the city, will send his geo-location to the app. Then, based on that location, the app will send back an array of informations, update the screen and even, probably, a (google) map

So say, if there are 10000 users connected at the same time, all moving around, there will be really a lot of requests to the app, every second.

I'm doing a little research about the best tecnologies to implement, and I found that maybe using websockets would be a good choice. Is that true?

They say that websockets are good for:

- Multiplayer online games
- Chat applications
- Live sports ticker
- Realtime updating social streams

Are they ALSO good for the type of app I'd like to build?

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets is only transport protocol and does not really solves the challenges you will face in development of your application.

First of all you need to decide if you are building Web app or Native app.

Then you need to consider scalability of your infrastructure in terms of concurrent connections as well as preparing responses - based on nearby locations (for example).

Few major questions you need to answer first:

1. How often geo-data will be sent.
2. How often updates of other locations should be updated on client-side
3. How you going to prevent cheating: If I send geo-location of airport while am in totally different place (as example).
4. On server side, how you are going to store locations data (mongodb has 2d indexing out of the box).
5. How you going to find nearest points, identify them and send to client?
6. Searching of nearby places - is expensive task, and requires a lot of optimizations like clustering of space, 2d indexing, etc.